# How can I access localstorage using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
module Layout {

    var a = localStorage.getItem('x');
    export class aaa {
        init() {;
            var xxx = localStorage.getItem('x');
        }
    }

}
```

In Visual Studio 2012 with the 0.8.1 version I am getting a message on the line inside the init() function saying "the name localStorage does not exist in the current scope". outside of the aaa class this works fine.  Is there something I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Both in VS 2012 + 0.8.1 and in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ , it works fine for me.

Comment: @Oldrich - Thanks. I'm not sure what happened but since my 0.8.1 upgrade we are getting this same problem everywhere in functions that are inside exported classes inside modules. It does not even recognize the JQuery dollar. Were you checking in the edit window? How did you compile the .ts to .js ?  I wonder if this is a problem with web essentials.

Comment: @Anne are you using Web Essentials?

Comment: @Steve - Yes. Sorry for the late reply. We are using Web Essentials. Actually we are not sure how to compile manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.8.1 version of TypeScript has caused a bug in Web Essentials. There should be a fix in a few days.

In the meantime, if you install the 0.8.0 version of TypeScript that works with the current version, or you can compile from command line:

```
tsc --debug c:\myapp\app.ts
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the beta update, you can rename the version number folder in the SDK from 0.8.1.0 to 0.8.0.0 - this is the issue for Web Essentials. I'm sure it will be out of beta pretty quick though!